# Python parser working, but get an index out of range error on my last result and not able to save list to file

Tags: python, parsing, scraper

I wrote a Python script to parse the info of shows from a local venue, to display the updated agenda on my home screen.

All prints out ok, but I get an String index out of range error on what I believe to be the last result.

The code is below. I appreciate any help to shed some light on this specific error.

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

#READ THE DESIRED URL
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.coliseu.pt/agenda/').read()

#PARSE THE HTML
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

#RESULTS WILL HOLD THE INFORMATION PARSED
results = []

#FIND ALL DIVS WITH CLASS BL-BLOCK, GATHER ALL THE TEXT
#AND CHECK FOR THE APROPRIATE RETURNS TO AVOID DUPLICATE FIELDS
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='bl-block'):
    row = [i.text for i in div]
    #FOR DEBUGGING
    print(row)
    if len(row) == 3 and row[2][0].isdigit():
        results.append(row)



#SAVE RESULTS TO FILE IF ANY ARE FOUND
if len(results) > 0:
    file = open('testfile.txt', 'w')
    for line in results:
        file.write(line + '\n')
    file.close()
```

I haven't gotten to the .txt file write method because I can't get past this error.

After the @Vahid solved the above problem, I now get encoding errors when trying to save this to a file.

As I'm working with a list, can't write the list directly to the file and any attempt of converting the list to a string keeps boucing the same error.

Can't figure a way to get the data into a file.

//UPDATED
Found out where the problem lies. I'm not able to encode the \u0327 character to UTF-8, can't understand why. The character is "ç" .

Tried encoding it to UTF-8 and to ASCII without success. I'd appreciate any help given.

Comment: Try changing the if statement like this: `if len(row) == 3 and len(row[2]) and row[2][0].isdigit():`
You're probably hitting an array item with zero length.

Comment: At a glance I think you need to surround row[2][[0] in a try catch as while len row ensures the first index is valid theres no checking on the second index and it may be null.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any `print`s where you look at the state of the variables before the error occurs.  That's step #1 in debugging.

Comment: Sorry, removed the print statement before posting. I'll update it as soon as I test Vahid's suggestion.

Comment: @HBT I had the same thought as Vahid and was going to suggest to print out row in the first for loop. For such kind of errors, I'd first do a print to see what's actually the content of the object in question.

Comment: Thank you, @Vahid. It fixed my problem. My last two prints were a 3 index list  and a 2 index list with empty strings. Probably the next would be a list with just an empty string.

Comment: Uh, saw you updated the codes with a print statement now. But you may not be able to see the problematic row because you may not get to the print statement in the if block because the test itself would give you the error. you should print row before the if block.

Comment: Thank you, @Shiping. It makes sense, but I had it here after following down the code to debug the first part of the code. Now trying to get the info on a file.